# Replace last part of string, javascript

Tags: javascript, string, ecmascript-6

```
const str = ".1.2.1"

const str2 = ".1";

const func = (str, str2) => {
 ...
}
```

expected output = `".1.2"`

Another example:

```
str = "CABC"
str2 = "C"
Expected output "CAB"
```

So the last part of the string that matches the end of the string should be removed.

Can this be done with some neat build-in-function in javascript?

> Update

Updated string example. Simple replace does not work.

Comment: What happened with _users posting questions are supposed to make a proper research and an effort of their own_?

Comment: @LGSon Believe me, compared to what was being posted over the weekend, this seems like a good question to me :P

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I've seen it all...still, no excuse IMHO. It is not a newbie here at SO

Comment: The funniest thing is the rat race of the guys with x10k of rep below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a regular expression from the string and preserve the dot by escaping it and use the end marker of the string to replace only the last occurence.

```js
const
    replace = (string, pattern) => string.replace(new RegExp(pattern.replace(/\./g, '\\\$&') + '$'), '')

console.log(replace(".1.2.1", ".1"));
console.log(replace("CABC", "C"));
```

Answer (score 5):

Just try replacing `\.\d+$` with empty string, using a regex replacement:

```js
var input = "1.2.1";
input = input.replace(/\.\d+$/, "");
console.log(input);
```

**Edit:**

Assuming the final portion of the input to be removed is actually contained in a string variable, then we might be forced to use `RegExp` and manually build the pattern:

```js
var str = "CABC"
var str2 = "C"
var re = new RegExp(str2 + "$");
str = str.replace(re, "");
console.log(str);
```

Comment: It appears this question as well was like the one's over the weekend, if you check their edit. Also made your answer invalid (or you were to fast to answer instead of asking if it always are numbers/dots)

Comment: @LGSon I updated my answer to the more general case.  It is generally rude to change a question after so many people have answered IMO.

Comment: Am aware, and agree...still, something we sometimes need to take :)

Answer (score 1):

You can check the position of the string to find using `lastIndexOf` and if it is at its supposed position, then just slice

```js
function removeLastPart(str, str2)
{
  result = str;
  
  let lastIndex = str.lastIndexOf(str2);
  if (lastIndex == (str.length - str2.length))
  {
    result = str.slice(0, lastIndex)
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(removeLastPart(".1.2.1", ".1"));
console.log(removeLastPart("CABC", "C"));
console.log(removeLastPart(" ispum lorem ispum ipsum", " ipsum"));

// should not be changed
console.log(removeLastPart("hello world", "hello"));
console.log(removeLastPart("rofllollmao", "lol"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.prototype.slice`

```js
const str = "1.2.1"

const str2 = ".1";

const func = (str) => {
 return str.slice(0, str.lastIndexOf("."));
}

console.log(func(str));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a dynamic regex using [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp). The `$` appended will replace `str2` from `str` ONLY if it is at the end of the string

```js
const replaceEnd = (str, str2) => {
  const regex = new RegExp(str2 + "$");
  return str.replace(regex, '')
}

console.log(replaceEnd('.1.2.1', '.1'))
console.log(replaceEnd('CABC', 'C'))
```